# Populating a Combo Box based on selection from Combo Box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a window form application. I want to populate a combo box based on what the person selects from the first combo box. all my records are stored in a single database table.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: you need an event handler on box one that gets called when its selected item changes. Use that to populate the second combo

Answer (score 0):

Like pm100 suggested, you'll need to be registered to the first combo box's `SelectedIndexChanged` event and when it gets fired you'll retrieve the second combo box's values based on the first combo box `SelectedText` or `SelectedItem` property.

For example, say you'll register to the event on form load event:

```
cbx1.SelectedIndexChanged += Cbx1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Then when the event gets fired:

```
private void Cbx1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     cbx2.Items.Clear(); // Clear to add new retreived items

     if (cbx1.SelectedIndex != -1)
     {
         // Retrieve the items based on cbx1's selected item
         var items = Repository.RetreiveItems(cbx1.SelectedText);
         cbx2.Items.AddRange(items);
     }
}
```

And that is basically it. 
You'll may want to consider retrieving the items asynchronously so that the UI will be free.